# FirefoxDriver - Connection is not secure

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

When I attempt to run my automation tests against Firefox 47.0.1 I get a warning mentioning that the connection is insecure. I have written the below code to resolve the issue, which unfortunately it's not working. If anyone has a solution that would be great.

```
if browser == 'firefox':
        profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
        profile.set_preference("webdriver_accept_untrusted_certs",  True)
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
```

Comment: Was your issue resolved?

Answer (score 1):

This occures because of 
`profile.set_preference("webdriver_accept_untrusted_certs",  True)`

Remove this and try instead:
`profile.set_preference("webdriver_assume_untrusted_issuer",  False)`
`profile.update_preferences()`

Comment: Thank you @George D, however I'm getting the following error now... WebDriverException: Message: Can't load the profile. Profile Dir: /var/folders/mv/cd5x9yjs4bj7cyjky7mbqzvm0006ps/T/tmphvSxGl If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.